# Windows Azure 'Design Your SQL Database' link not working

Tags: azure

I'm following the example in chapter 13 of Adam Freeman's book Pro ASP.NET MVC5 where he uploads the sample application to the Windows Azure cloud.  In the example he show that the database is set up by clicking the 'Design Your SQL Database' link in the 'Connect To Your Database' section.

When I click this link, the spinning wheel is activated to show that the click has been registered, but then nothing happens.  This is the first time that I've used Azure and I was wondering if anyone had any ideas why the link doesn't work.  I have Silverlight 5 installed and the I've followed the tutorial to the letter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. Have you figured out how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem using Chrome, and spent hours trying to find a solution.

I finally tried using IE instead, and was prompted to allow popups. Once I selected "always allow" the database form displayed as shown in the book.